# While adding data to Datable/DataRow getting the error as "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." in UiPath

Tags: automation, rpa, uipath, uipath-studio

I am working on a excel automation project in UiPath, where need to update few details from one excel to other and while updating, the logic is working fine for first 2 entries after that getting the error as:

"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Initialized the new Data Table and created a new Row in Data table.

Both the Keys and Values are not empty, but not sure why I am getting that issue.

Thanks
Harsha

Comment: Some images of the process and the properties maybe?

Comment: Yes, some images or additional information would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have create a new Data table, at the time of adding the new data columns in the Add Data Column Activity the Auto Increment was auto enabled that has created the issue. After disabling that the issue was resolved.